# Email piping with PHP script – required_once(‘/filepath/class.foo.php’) not recognized

Tags: php, email, filepath, require-once, piping

I have the following code which works fine until I try to include an external PHP file which is in the same directory.
class.foo.php permission level 777. Parent directory permission set to 777
In the delivery fail response I get: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'foo' not found in /home/myname/public_html/pipemail/pipemail.php on line 49

My code is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php
require_once('./class.foo.php');
//Listen to incoming e-mails
$sock = fopen ("php://stdin", 'r');
$email = '';
//Read e-mail into buffer
while (!feof($sock))
{
    $email .= fread($sock, 1024);
}
//Close socket
fclose($sock);
//$email .= 'this is a test';
$foo = new foo();
?>
```

I have tried

```
require_once('/class.foo.php');
require_once('/home/myname/public_html/pipemail/class.foo.php');
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe there is no such class in the file?

Comment: include_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/class.foo.php"; did the trick. Thanks for the suggestion. There are two underscores before and after FILE... just does not show up here.

Answer (score 0):

Change to `require'/home/myname/public_html/pipemail/foo.php';` 
it looks like this :

```
<?php require'/home/myname/public_html/pipemail/foo.php';

.....
.....
.....

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . "/class.foo.php"; // PHP >= 5.3

require dirname(__FILE__) . "/class.foo.php";  // PHP < 5.3

?>
```